# Why can actix_rt be used directly in the code, even if it wasn't declared?

Tags: rust, rust-actix

I just added actix_rt in Cargo.toml and didn't declare it at the first line with the use keyword. Then I could use it in the code. I know some frequently used functions are included in the prelude of Rust, but I had no idea 3rd party libraries could do the some thing. Can I create a crate like that?

Any one could tell me why or give me some tips or some reference links? I'd appreciate it.

```
[dependencies]
actix-rt = "0.2.5"
actix-web = "1.0.8"
```

```
use std::io;

fn main() -> io::Result<()> {
    let sys = actix_rt::System::new("basic");

    sys.run()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Rust 2018 Edition, `extern crate` [is no longer required](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/edition-guide/rust-2018/module-system/path-clarity.html). Putting a crate as a dependency allows it to be accessed as a module. There's nothing you need to do to make your crate accessible like this.

This is very different from the standard library prelude, which `use`s all the items in the prelude implicitly [(with `use std::prelude::v1::*;`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/prelude/index.html)). With `extern crate` or adding an external crate as a dependency, the types, functions and traits have to be qualified. In your example, you have to use `actix_rt::System::new("basic")` rather than simply `System::new("basic")`. Compare this to `std::prelude::v1::Option`, which can be used as `Option<T>` without any prefix.